# Multi-Output Regression with neural network in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, regression

I have got an .xlsx Excel file with an input an 2 output columns. And there are some coordinates and outputs in that file such as:
x= 10 y1=15 y2=20
x= 20 y1=14 y2=22 ...
I am trying to do that regression using tensorflow. But somehow i can't manage to do it. I am leaving my code here, I would appraciate it if someone could help! I also have test datas ready as well.

```
training_data = pd.read_excel(...\training_data.xlsx',sheet_name="i1-o2")

training_data_X = training_data['i1']

training_data_Y = training_data[['o1','o2']]

testing_data = data = pd.read_excel(....\testing_data.xlsx',sheet_name="i1-o2")

testing_data_X = testing_data['i1']

testing_data_Y = testing_data[['o1','o2']]


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='linear')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_data_X,training_data_Y,epochs=10,batch_size=100)

val_loss,val_acc = model.evaluate(testing_data_X,testing_data_Y)
print(val_loss,val_acc)
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Well, I am having an issue about the line model.fit(training_data_X,....) It says its not possible or something like that.

Comment: I'd just like to add a quick comment: you are doing regression, why using 'accuracy' as metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some mistakes:

1. input data must be `numpy` objects, not `pandas`
2. this Network has 6 output nodes, not 2
3. the number of layers is completely exagerated IMHO
4. the `Flatten()` layer at the beginning is not correct
5. the way you called ReLU's is not correct

This should be enough:

```
from tf.keras.models import Sequential
from tf.keras.layers import Dense
from tf.keras.activations import relu

model = Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = relu),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = relu),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = None)
])
```

Check if the loss works at this point. Alternatively, you need to write your own custom loss function using Keras backend functions.

Comment: Alright, It looks like i managed to fix the problems. The last thing that i would like to ask is if you could help me with drawing graph. Any tips? Thanx even if you cant help..

Comment: I admit I never tried to draw graphs... But I'd suggest you to use the TensorBoard. There are other python libraries that can do that within Jupyter Notebook, but I admit I never looked for that. Sorry

Comment: Thank you for your helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a Flatten layer in this?
seems like it is already a numerical data.

and as @desertnaut mentioned, since this is a regression setup, you should be using mse or mae